# Android - Masking a View

Tags: android, masking

I have a FrameLayout that has a background, and contains a ViewPager that I can slide through Views. I also have a PNG image that I want to use as a mask on the ViewPager, so that I can retain my background, but only show a portion of the ViewPager element. In essence, I want to create a custom masking effect as shown [here](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=230&cpage=1#comment-35184) but instead of applying that to an image, I want to apply that to a View. How can I do this?

I started out with:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/mask"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The image I'm using basically has a cutout in the PNG file so there's a transparent portion. The problem with using this technique is there's a portion of the image that has a gradient. By doing a proper mask, I was hoping that characters would "fade" in but instead, it's now just starkly appearing as in you can see the edge of where it appears, so it's not pretty. If anyone has better ideas how to mask it cleanly, I'm open to them...